# Export related work items from pull request

Tags: git, azure-devops

Is there any way to export the list of related work items in a Git pull request in Azure DevOps?

Comment: Hi. We actually used a custom Query to pull all work items from several sprints, and that was it. Since I didn't have the chance to try Shamrai's answers myself, I can't accept them. When I have the chance, I'll try automating that process further. Maybe then I'll be able to accept

Comment: Feel free to check these answers and kindly let us know the result.

Answer (score 6):

Azure CLI can view linked work items:  [az repos pr work-item list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/repos/pr/work-item?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_repos_pr_work_item_list)

Template:

```
az repos pr work-item list --org https://dev.azure.com/{org} --id {id} --output table
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use REST API: [Pull Request Work Items - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

You can just put into the browser the following template:

[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/workitems?api-version=6.1-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/git/repositories/%7Brepository%7D/pullRequests/%7BpullRequestId%7D/workitems?api-version=6.1-preview.1)

[image]